# two forloop inside in one table row

Tags: django

I have 2 loops from views which is generates in my table.

```
<tr style='height:19px;'>
<th id="703183278R33" style="height: 19px;" class="row-headers-background">
<div class="row-header-wrapper" style="line-height: 19px;">34</div>
</th>
<td class="s46"></td>
<td class="s51" colspan="3">Subject</td>
<td class="s51" colspan="4">Teacher</td>
<td class="s51" colspan="6">Room and Schedule</td>

<td class="s0"></td>
</tr>
{% for sensie in teacher %}

<tr style='height:19px;'>
<th id="703183278R34" style="height: 19px;" class="row-headers-background">
<div class="row-header-wrapper" style="line-height: 19px;">35</div>
</th>

<td class="s46"></td>
<td class="s51" colspan="3">{{sensie.Subjects}}</td>
<td class="s51" colspan="4">{{sensie.Employee_Users}}</td>
{% endfor %}
{% for room in roomsched %}
<td class="s51" colspan="6">{{room.Classroom}}-{{room.Day_Name}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

\views

```
studentenroll = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(Student_Users=id)
      studentgrade =  StudentsEnrollmentRecord.Education_Levels
      FeesType = SchoolFeesMasterList.objects.filter(Education_Levels__in=studentenroll.values_list('Education_Levels'))
      #payment = StudentsPaymentSchedule.objects.filter(Students_Enrollment_Records__in=studentenroll)"payment":payment,
      teacher = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(Education_Levels__in=studentenroll.values_list('Education_Levels'))
      roomsched = SubjectRoomSchedule.objects.filter(Subject_Section_Teacher__in=teacher)
      #teachers = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(),"teacher":teacher
      return render(request, 'Homepage/enrollmentrecords.html',{"studentenroll":studentenroll,"SchoolFeesType":FeesType,"teacher":teacher,"roomsched":roomsched})
```

how do i make it so that it gets formatted in table properly? just like on the example below.

```
Subject             Teacher               Room and Schedule
math               example-Teacher          room1-mwf
```

Comment: You need to share your views and models for this

Answer (score 0):

First try single loop then try second loop .

```
<table>
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>subject</th>
         <th>teacher</th>
         <th>Room and </th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       {% for sensie in teacher %}  # FIRST LOOP 
         <tr>
           <td>{{ sensie.Subjects}}</td>
           <td>{{ sensie.employee_Users }}</td>


        {% for room in roomsched %}    # SECOND LOOP
           <td>{{ room.Classroom }}</td>
         </tr>
       {% endfor %}    


     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new dictionary that appends both of dicts to the returned context. This way you will use only 1 loop.

Comment: can you show me the request which is
   return render(request,  'x.html', context)

Comment: return render(request, 'Homepage/enrollmentrecords.html',{"studentenroll":studentenroll,"SchoolFeesType":FeesType,"teacher":teacher,"roomsched":roomsched})